# Ghostery Lite stopped blocking ads

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

After a power failure - or perhaps an auto-system-update? - Ghostery Lite is no longer blocking ads. I have tried updating it (no updates available), ensuring it is enabled in Safari, turning ad blocking on and off, used Advanced checkboxes, etc, but no luck. Arstechnica is now almost unusable.

Any advice? Their web site contains very little on the topic of debugging and my posts for support are unanswered.

Comment: try uninstall -> reinstall ? Also see if it's just arstechnica or any other ad loaded website too : https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Tools

Comment: It's all pages - ars, /. etc. Test pages appear to fail (if I'm reading them correctly).